# Higher dimensional analog to planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

We usually say that a graph is planar if it can be embedded into 2-space s.t. no edges intersect.  Here's a different way to describe the same situation: a graph is planar if it can be embedded into 2-space s.t. the edges form the boundaries of cells which nowhere overlap.

**My question:** Can you take this second definition and extend the idea to higher dimensions?  For instance, allow the cells to be volumes in 3-space - like soap bubbles where the graph edges are the intersection of soap film walls.

Comment: Intuitively it seems that such "cell" construction would have bounded doubling dimensions, whereas planar graphs can have unbounded doubling dimension

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A planar graph is nothing other than a [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)) of the $2$-sphere (via [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)), at least if one allows arbitrary polygons instead of just triangles, so a natural generalization to three dimensions is triangulations of the $3$-sphere where one allows arbitrary (convex) polyhedra instead of just simplices. One can of course talk about triangulations of arbitrary manifolds.

Comment: When you say "triangulation", do you mean representing vertices of a graph as points in the space? I have trouble imagining how tree structured-graphs fit into this construction

Comment: @Yaroslav: yes. See my comment to your answer. If this isn't a good definition for you, pretend I'm actually talking about CW-complexes.

Comment: I think Qiaochu means tesselating.

Comment: ... although that might still not be precise here...

Comment: Tangent: One of the proofs of Sylvester-Gallai theorem uses this planar graph representation.

Answer (score 2):

Another generalization is along the genus axis, i.e., consider which graphs can be embedded into a 2d compact surface, such as an $n$-torus. This area is called [topological graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_graph_theory).

Comment: That's kind a interesting.

Comment: @John: Perhaps a better analog of planar graphs would use geodesic embededdings, not merely topological ones. That is, the edges would be geodesics. I don't know whether topological graph theory handles this nor whether there is a "Riemannian graph theory" out there. I did find the paper "A Riemannian approach to graph embedding", http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2006.05.031 , which seems to contains some references for this approach.

Comment: perhaps, but when we start talking about geodesics, we're getting away from the more pure topological questions I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about your definition, for a graph below, what are cells and boundaries?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/blog/cholesky/kary-orig.png))</sub>

Comment: There is one infinite cell, and its boundary consists of every edge.

Comment: what Qiaochu said

Answer (score 0):

Another -- I think more natural -- concept is the (PL)-*embeddability* of $k$-dimensional simplicial complexes into $R^d$, for certain pairs $k,d$. The case $k=1$, $d=2$ is graph planarity.

There are many recent algorithmic result on this, including polynmiality in the metastable dimension range ($d\geq 3(k+1)/2$) with fixed dimensions, NP-hardness (and probably undecidability) for larger $k$, and proven undecidability for $k=d$.